# deserializing json object from SPARQL query by gson error

Tags: android, deserialization, gson, sparql, dbpedia

I have a problem in deserializing json object coming from DBpedia by a sparql query.
i'm using gson to deserialize it and used this tool to generate the Object Class: jsongen.byingtondesign.com

the JSON output of the sparql query url:
http://goo.gl/b4oF1

or:
http://labs.tedux.com/sparqlDONE.json

when i used the generated classes inside the android SDK i got an error in one of them because of this:

```
 {
    type: "literal",
    xml:lang: "en",......
```

so i removed this **xml:lang**  from the class but when i tried to deserialize the object by gson i got the whole json object deserialized expect the description class.
do you have any idea to be able to deserialize it??

---

The Description class:

```
import java.util.List;

public class Description{
private String type;
private String value;
private String xml:lang;

public String getType(){
    return this.type;
}
public void setType(String type){
    this.type = type;
}
public String getValue(){
    return this.value;
}
public void setValue(String value){
    this.value = value;
}
public String getXml:lang(){
    return this.xml:lang;
}
public void setXml:lang(String xml:lang){
    this.xml:lang = xml:lang;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your java class won't compile as the colon isn't valid syntax.

The main problem was the original json... Colons aren't valid as property names in json either.

So you should change your json to look like this:

```
{
    type: "literal",
    xmllang: "en"
}
```

Then regenerate you class files.

Answer (score 0):

i get over that by making a PHP Webservice and now i just query my Webservices to get a customized Json Object for my android app.